# Generate a list from HTML elements using Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium and BeautifulSoup to create a few lists from wikipedia pages. When I look at the page source, the links I want to get the information from are always structured as:

```
<li><a href="/wiki/town_name,_California" title="town_name, California">town_name, state</a></li>
```

There is a link within the tag that you can click on that will direct you to that town's wiki page. It is always `/wiki/town_name,_California`

I want to use a for loop in Python to find every item with this structure but am unclear how to write the regular expression. I tried:

```
my_link = "//wiki//*,California"
```

and

```
my_link = "//wiki//*,_California"
```

But when I tried to run:

```
 br.find_element_by_link_text(my_link)
```

These returned similar errors:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"//wiki//*,_California"}
```

I also tried:

```
import selenium, time
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
pg_src = br.page_source.encode("utf")
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg_src)
br = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "http://somewikipage.org"

br.get(url)

lnkLst = []
for lnk in br.find_element_by_partial_link_text(",_California"):
    lnkLst.append(lnk)
```

and got this:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":",_California"}
```

Is there any way I can correct this code so I can build a list of my targeted links?

Comment: You grab the page source, with soup.  Loop through the soup for the links.

Comment: @IamBatman tried soup.select("a[href*=,_California]") and got ValueError: Unsupported od invalid CSS selector "a[href*="

Comment: @IamBatman got this to work: soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(",_California")). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your Question that `br.find_element_by_partial_link_text(",_California")` didn't work that's because `,_California` is not really the `link_text` as per the `HTML` you provided.

As per your question we need to find the `<a>` tage which contains the attribute `href="/wiki/town_name,_California"`. So you can use any of the following options:

- **`css_selector`**:

  ```
  br.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href=/wiki/town_name,_California]")
  ```
- **`xpath`**:

  ```
  br.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/wiki/town_name,_California']")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on css selectors, they are your friend. I think the following should work.

```
hrefs = [a.href for a in soup.select('li a[href^="/wiki/"]')]
```

Comment: Taking a look at the css selectors but having a problem isolating the right ones. I plugged in your code and it returned a list of Nones.